# Hibernate Second-level Cache not using JBoss Infinispan custom region config

Tags: hibernate, jboss, infinispan

We have a project using

- JBoss EAP 7.4.4.GA (WildFly Core 15.0.8.Final-redhat-00001)
- Hibernate 5.3.25.Final-redhat-00002

Second-level cache is configured as described in [JBoss documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html/development_guide/java_persistence_api_jpa#configure_a_second_level_cache_for_hibernate) in "persistence.xml":

```
<shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
...
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.cache.region_prefix" value="sskm-v2-region" />
<property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.statistics" value="true" />
```

In "standalone.xml" Infinispan is configured:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:12.0">
        ...
        <cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="default-sskm-v2-cache" statistics-enabled="true" modules="org.infinispan.hibernate-cache">
            <local-cache name="entity">
                <heap-memory size="10000"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="local-query">
                <heap-memory size="10000"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="timestamps"/>
            <local-cache name="pending-puts">
                <expiration max-idle="60000"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="default-sskm-v2-cache">
                <heap-memory size="1000"/>
                <expiration lifespan="1200000" max-idle="1200000"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="query.cache.LegalContext">
                <heap-memory size="500"/>
                <expiration interval="500" max-idle="1000"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="be.fgov.kszbcss.sskm.model.legalcontext.LegalContext">
                <heap-memory size="1000"/>
            </local-cache>
        </cache-container>
    </subsystem>
```

Expiration has been modified for easy testing: default caches don't expire, custom query cache expires after 1s.

Query caching is enabled for relevant queries using a wrapper method:

```
    private <T> TypedQuery<T> createTypedQuery(CriteriaQuery<T> criteriaQuery) {
        TypedQuery<T> typedQuery = getEntityManager().createQuery(criteriaQuery);
        if (cacheQueries) {
            typedQuery.setHint(QueryHints.HINT_CACHEABLE, true);
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(cacheRegion)) {
                typedQuery.setHint(QueryHints.HINT_CACHE_REGION, cacheRegion);
            }
        }
        return typedQuery;
    }
```

Despite all this configuration caching simply refuses to use the custom "query.cache.LegalContext" cache and uses the values of "local-query" (default query cache). Example run:

```
2022-07-04 10:50:22,229 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (default task-1) {} WFLYCLINF0002: Started sskm-v2-region.query.cache.LegalContext cache from hibernate container
2022-07-04 10:50:22,230 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cache.internal.QueryResultsCacheImpl] (default task-1) {} Checking cached query results in region: query.cache.LegalContext
2022-07-04 10:50:22,231 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cache.internal.QueryResultsCacheImpl] (default task-1) {} Query results were not found in cache
...
2022-07-04 10:51:30,599 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cache.internal.QueryResultsCacheImpl] (default task-1) {} Checking cached query results in region: query.cache.LegalContext
2022-07-04 10:51:30,599 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cache.internal.QueryResultsCacheImpl] (default task-1) {} Returning cached query results
```

So it's clear the query is using caching but we see a cache hit where a miss was expected. I've

- Attempted to add/remove region prefix but no success
- Explicitly defined the Infinispan region factory in "persistence.xml" but no success
- Tested with entities themselves and observed same behavior (only using default "entity" config)

**So entities & queries are successfully being cached, but I'm simply not able to override the cache config for specific regions. What could be the cause for this?**

Answer (score 1):

To override the cache configuration for a specific region, you need to indicate how the regions map to cache configurations in your persistence.xml:

```xml
<property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.region-name.cfg" value="cache-name"/>
```

In your case, you probably want something like:

```xml
<property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.be.fgov.kszbcss.sskm.model.legalcontext.LegalContext.cfg" value="be.fgov.kszbcss.sskm.model.legalcontext.LegalContext"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.query.cache.LegalContext.cfg" value="query.cache.LegalContext"/>
```

For further details, see:
https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/hibernate/hibernate.html